# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 200.142.86.219:443 using google cloud functions appears randomly

Tags: node.js, request, gcloud, request-promise

I've been trying to make a request using node.js with request-promise library and gCloudFunctions located in US to a webpage located in Brazil. When I get access to it, I login with my data.

The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, when it doesn't I get the following error on my log:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxx
```

In my local machine the error never occurs, it only happens on gCloud Functions.

What I've done so far:

- Retried the requests for more 3 times (on the same initial page), if it didn't work at first attempt, it never worked on the next retries.
- Tried to access a different webpage, then the desired one, same as before, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.
- Inserted on my default options requested `rejectUnauthorized: false`. This stabilised the app for about 24h, then the error started occurring again.

My request is set like this:

```
options = {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            jar: true,
            headers: {
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Host": "xxx.xxx.xxx.br",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36",
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            },
};
```

I don't know exactly how to generate the error, but when it occurs normally it keeps occurring and after some time the request works, then stops, and so on.

My guesses are about firewall and TSL on google cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue migrating to another server in Brazil, probably the server that I was trying to access was blocking my requests my guess is because they were located far away from each other and was rejecting this 'less' priority requests. Also made my requests way faster!